# Unable to uploading .class file on server using FTP java

Tags: java, ftp, ftp-server

I want to upload a .class file (ABC.class) on server using FTP.

Tried: 
1>

```
public boolean uploadFileOnFTPServer(File file, String uploadToPath) {
    boolean isUploaded = false;
    try {
        FileInputStream bis = new FileInputStream(file);
        if (connectToFTPServer()) {
            if (ftpClient.login(userName, password)) {
                System.out.println("Logged in to server. Username: " + userName);
                if (ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(uploadToPath)) {
                    System.out.println("Navigated to path " + uploadToPath);

                    if (ftpClient.storeFile(file.getName(), bis)) {
                        bis.close();
                        System.out.println("File " + file.getName() + " uploaded to server.");
                        isUploaded = true;
                    }
                } 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        strRemarks = "Exception reported: Unable to upload file. Error Details: " + e.toString();
        System.out.println(strRemarks);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        disconnectFTPServer();
    }
    return isUploaded;
}
```

Also tried:

2>

```
InputStream bis = new FileInputStream(file);
```

3>

```
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
```

The file is getting uploaded on server but its corrupted or content is not getting stored in file correctly.

Any one can please help.

Comment: You're calling methods and referring to variables none of which are defined here. How are we supposed to help without knowing what's happening offstage? But the most likely problem is that you're sending the file in ASCII (text) mode; you need to use IMAGE (binary) mode.

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience. `connectToFTPServer() - function to connect to server


ftpClient - FTPClient ftpClient = null;


disconnectFTPServer() - function to get disconnected from server


I tried: ftpClient.setFileType(FTPClient.ASCII_FILE_TYPE);`  didnt work

Comment: Set it to NOT the ASCII file type! The ASCII type is the wrong type, but it's the default!

Comment: `ftpClient.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);` Not working :(

Comment: Try to determine *how* it is corrupted. Is it the right size? Are certain byte values replaced consistently, or is it just garbage? Use the "od -t x2" command on Linux (for example) to examine the contents of good and corrupted class files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

**Adding setFileType() after getting connected to server but before transfer of file.**

```
                    ftpClient.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);                 
                    String remoteFileName = file.getName();
                    if (ftpClient.storeFile(remoteFileName, inputStream)) {
                        inputStream.close();
                        System.out.println("File " + file.getName() + " uploaded to server.");
                        isUploaded = true;
                    }
```

Thanks a lot to EJP for helping me with this :)